# Swap Not detected

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, swap

i recently finished shanto-imon) + and now Started Studying CHF so i needed 3 in 1 System and installed Windows 7 + ubuntu 14.04.5 + parrotsec (debian pentesting os),
as i was installing 3 os in grub for the very first time i created swap for ubuntu and after completing installation ubuntu i created another swap for parrotsec os now they are like

1. windows Disks
2. Parrotsec disk
3. parrotsec swap
4. linux disk
5. linux swap

   screenshot:

   sudo update-grub

   [image: Grub Os list]

but the problem is when i run ubuntu 14.04.5 i see there is no swap memory detected as it shown on the screenshot below: 
[image: No Swap memory detected]

here is my disk's screenshot for better understanding: [image: Disk's]

i want the os to detect the swap memory not only Ubuntu but also other (if it possible to solve other os's swap memory Problem via ubuntu)

thanks in advance .

Comment: In terminal, type: "sudo blkid", and then edit /etc/fstab and make sure that your UUID's for the swap partition match. Then type: "swapon -a". You'll have to do this separately for each Linux OS.

Comment: # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb7 during installation
UUID=876a767a-d428-4b7e-8017-64bb8772a663 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb8 during installation
UUID=f8b2c6c8-2f92-4d4c-9a79-31bd432ee4b2 none            swap    sw              0       0

Comment: what to do now ??

Comment: You need to do the "sudo blkid" command and match up the UUID for the swap partition in /etc/fstab.